# How to properly count bytes for procedure RET in Assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

```
    .data
    
    intro1              BYTE    "Generating, Sorting, and Counting Random integers!  Programmed by chris",13,10,0
    intro2              BYTE    "This program generates 200 random numbers within the range 10-29, displays the",13,10
                        BYTE    "original list, sorts the list, displays the median value of the list, displays the",13,10
                        BYTE    "list sorted in ascending order, then displays the number of instances of each",13,10
                        BYTE    "generated value, starting with the number of 10s.",13,10,13,10,0
    
    .code
main PROC
    ;intro
    push    OFFSET intro1            ; 12
    push    OFFSET intro2            ; 8
    call    Introduction

    ;fillArray
    ;push   OFFSET  unsortNumMsg    ; 8
    ;call   fillArray

    Invoke ExitProcess,0    ; exit to operating system
main ENDP

; -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; procedure header
; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Introduction PROC
    push    EBP
    mov     EBP, ESP
    
    ; prints title 
    mov     EDX, [EBP + 12]
    call    WriteString

    ; prints out rules for user
    mov     EDX, [EBP + 8]
    call    WriteString

    RET     8
Introduction ENDP
```

Getting a frame not in module error, I'm definitely not returning the right amount of bytes. There's more of this project that I'm going to have to be returning in a similar fashion so I wanted to ask what's the proper way of determining how many bytes to return, using this code above as an example.

Thanks!

Comment: The `RET 8` itself is fine but you forgot to `POP EBP` beforehand.

Comment: oh! thanks, this worked.

Comment: Also notice that you can use ESP instead of EBP for addressing, and omit `push EBP`  and `mov EBP, ESP`.